# What is the meaning of "assisted interaction"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Searching Google didn't help much and in the context below, it was related closely to "face-to-face interaction".

> Citizens may also simply prefer face-to-face or **assisted interaction** when applying for benefits, permits or otherwise engaging with institutions on personal matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assisted interaction** refers to a digital interaction made by an individual citizen (via internet) through an [E-government](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-Government) website requesting information or applying for government service(s), or, for that matter, paying bills.

It is an official UN term  ([Division for Public Administration and Development Management](http://unpan3.un.org/egovkb/Reports/UN-E-Government-Survey-2014)) and can be found in its UN E-Government Survey(s).

A USA "related" term is Animal-Assisted Interaction ([AAI](http://www.vet.utk.edu/socialwork/about/animal-assisted-interactions.php)) which is a new form of therapy.

Comment: the text is actually kind of related to the mentioned surveys but in this context, doesn't the "assisted interaction" oppose "online interaction"?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be contrasting "face-to-face or assisted interaction" with other ways of claiming benefits and the like — presumably via a website; or possibly simply completing a form at home and mailing it in.

Many people prefer to talk to someone rather than type into a machine [can't think why!] and *assisted interaction* simply means that someone is there to help filling in the form. If this assistance is not **actually** face-to-face then the assistance may be via some sort of chat interface, or even by phone.

Comment: :the text actually IS contrasting those two with online interactions. but the way it does, is really important to me. assist by humans as you said makes sense but doesn't the meaning become way too similar to face-to-face interaction?

Comment: @EricCartman You're right; I should have enumerated the possibilities. Now done.